# Заблокировать сайт в hosts

Tags: windows-10, hosts

Не могу заблокировать сайт в hosts
в конец файла добавляю строки

```
127.0.0.1 vk.com
127.0.0.1 www.vk.com
```

однако доступ к ним имею

Пробовал следующее:

- удалять и заново создавать файл
- ipconfig /flushdns и перезагрузка компьютера после добавления строк

использую обычное интернет соединение, не прокси

Comment: Чтобы такого не происходило, нужно запускать текстовый редактор от админа, тогда будет сохранять нормально. И ничего никуда не нужно будет перекидывать.

Comment: У меня он по дефолту от админа запускается, так что хз

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы все работало делай так:

1. Скопируй файл "hosts" на рабочий стол.
2. В файле, который на рабочем столе внеси изменения и сохрани.
3. Замени оригинальный файл.

Если не помогло, возможно ты что-то наковырял, в этом случае:
Удали оригинальный файл "hosts" перезагрузи компьютер, нудно что бы система создала файл. Как появится файл, повтори все с пункта 1.

И попробуй добавить две записи:

```
127.0.0.1 vk.com
0.0.0.0 vk.com
```

Comment: проблема в том, что система не создает новый файл

Answer (score -5):

Проблема была в том, что файл hosts стал файлом hosts.txt, что недопустимо. Решением проблемы стало перекидывание файла с другого компьютера и изменением уже готового файла.